# C programing error with TC77 sensor

Tags: c

I am working with SPI and a temperature sensor TC77 in xilinx SDK, everything is working fine except this subprogram, where I need to get the proper temperature, but the output is " the temperature is ... no putput, what could be the error

```
#include "xparameters.h"    
#include "xspi.h"       
#include "xspi_l.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "xstatus.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "xil_cache.h"
#include "xbasic_types.h"

#define SPI_DEVICE_ID             XPAR_SPI_0_DEVICE_ID           
#define SPI_SELECT 0x01
#define BUFFER_SIZE     8          received

XSpi SpiInstance; 

u8 SendBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE]; 
u8 RecvBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

int Spi_Test(XSpi *SpiInstancePtr, u16 SpiDeviceId);

int main(void)

{
int Status;

for (;;)
{

Status = Spi_Test(&SpiInstance, SPI_DEVICE_ID);
if (Status != XST_SUCCESS) {
    return XST_FAILURE;
}
}
return XST_SUCCESS;
}

int Spi_Test(XSpi *SpiInstancePtr, u16 SpiDeviceId)
{
    int Status;
    int i,j;

    XSpi_Config *ConfigPtr; /* Pointer to Configuration data */

    /*****  Initialize the SPI driver ******/

    ConfigPtr = XSpi_LookupConfig(SPI_DEVICE_ID);
    if (ConfigPtr == NULL) {
        return XST_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND;
    }

    XSpi_CfgInitialize(SpiInstancePtr, ConfigPtr,
            ConfigPtr->BaseAddress);

    XSpi_SetOptions(SpiInstancePtr,
            XSP_MASTER_OPTION | XSP_MANUAL_SSELECT_OPTION);

    XSpi_GetSlaveSelect(SpiInstancePtr);

    XSpi_SetSlaveSelect(SpiInstancePtr, SPI_SELECT);

    XSpi_Start(SpiInstancePtr);

    XSpi_IntrGlobalDisable(SpiInstancePtr);

    /***** switch to Continuous mode to get the temperature, connect MOSI pin *****/
        /*SendBuffer[0] = 0x00;
        SendBuffer[1] = 0x00;

        Status = XSpi_Transfer(SpiInstancePtr, SendBuffer, RecvBuffer, 2);
        if (Status != XST_SUCCESS) {
        return XST_FAILURE;
        }*/

    /**** Get the temperature in RecvBuffer[0]& RecvBuffer [1]****/

        XSpi_Transfer(SpiInstancePtr, SendBuffer, RecvBuffer, 2);

        xil_printf("MSB of Temperature Register is = 0x%x\r\n", RecvBuffer[0]);
        xil_printf("LSB of Temperature Register is = 0x%x\r\n", RecvBuffer[1]);

        // sign bit method

        int sign = RecvBuffer[0] & 0x80;
        int tempValue =0;
        float tempCelsius;

        if (sign == 0)
        {
            tempValue = (RecvBuffer[0] << 8 | RecvBuffer[1]) >> 3;
            tempCelsius = (float) tempValue * 0.0625;
            xil_printf("The temperature is p = %3.1f \n\r", tempCelsius);
        }
        else
        if (sign == 1)
        {
            tempValue= (((RecvBuffer[0] & 0x7f) << 8 | RecvBuffer[1]) >> 3) - 4096;
            tempCelsius = (float) tempValue * 0.0625;
            xil_printf("The temperature is p = %3.1f \n\r", tempCelsius);
        }
            return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there no output at all, or just 0?

Comment: strange formatting of your else case

Comment: Maybe it is not a programming error but a general problem with the communication over SPI

Comment: with the SPI the communication is ok, as I have checked the individual registers and Im getting the desired temperature, there is output in hexadecimal, but I want the output in floating point by checking the signed bit. the output with floating point is "the temperature is ="

Comment: Are you sure that `xil_printf()` supports printing of floats? According to this [link](http://compgroups.net/comp.arch.fpga/xil_printf-not-working-as-expected-cont/260427) it doesn't.

Comment: yes u are right abt xil_print, i tried using %3.1f also, but same error,

Comment: Of course it does not work with `%3.1f`, you are still trying to use a `float`, which is not supported, please see my answer.

Comment: i have tried using printf and getting the result.. thanks a lot

Comment: can u plz tell the correct way to use xil_printf for floating point numbers instead of printf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not assigned the evaluation of

```
(((RecvBuffer[0] & 0x7f) << 8 | RecvBuffer[1]) >> 3) - 4096;
```

Did you mean the code to be this?

```
if (signBit == 0)
    tempValue= (RecvBuffer[0] << 8 | RecvBuffer[1]) >> 3; 
else
    tempValue= (((RecvBuffer[0] & 0x7f) << 8 | RecvBuffer[1]) >> 3) - 4096;
float tempCelsius = (float) tempValue * 0.0625;
xil_printf("The temperature is = %f \n\r", tempCelsius);
```

**EDIT**

I searched this and was informed *`xil_printf()` doesn't support %f, it only supports %d,l,x,c,s.* You have to print two integers, in the case of a positive value:

```
int whole, thousandths;
whole = tempCelsius;
thousandths = (tempCelsius - whole) * 1000;
xil_printf("%d.%03d\n", whole, thousandths);
```

[This](http://www.xilinx.com/ise/embedded/edk82i_docs/sa_oslib_libxil_stdc.pdf) document says of `xil_printf()`: *"This function is similar to printf but much smaller in size (only 1 kB). It does not have support for floating point numbers."*

Comment: I tried with the assigned variable as well, but there is no output in floating poiint.

Comment: I am posting the complete code to review plz.. yes u are right abt sil_print, i tried using %3.1f also

Comment: I made a small change to the format to 0-pad the thousands.

Comment: i have tried using printf and getting the result and with ur suggested way.. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Slightly off topic due to computer language, but, the code in this repo 
https://github.com/robin48gx/TH7
reads a TC77 in python.
However, this is relevant because....

The tc77 output  is a signed 13 bit number, situated
in the top 13 bits of a 16 bit word. ALSO you must write the last 16 bits AS ZEROS to command the tc77 to stay in continuous read mode. The
python code in that repo deals with all that. However, in `C' 
you may be able to cast this to a 16 bit int (often a 'short int'
but check your compiler/implementation). This can solve the sign
problem.

See also:
http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/20092a.pdf .